# How to set a variable equivalent to single array object while iterating through array?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, scripting

Noob question. I need to pass 3,000+ URLs from a CSV sheet to Selenium. I need Selenium to navigate to each one of these links, scrape information and then put that information into a CSV.

The issue I am running into is when I push my CSV URLS into an array, I cannot pass one single object (url) into Selenium at a time.

I know I likely need some sort of loop. I have tried setting up loops and selecting from the array using .map, .select. and just a do loop.

```
urls.map do |url|
    @driver.navigate.to #{url}
    name = @driver.find_element(:css, '.sites-embed- 
footer>a').attribute('href')
    puts name
    kb_link = name
    kb_array.push(kb_link)
    puts 'urls is #{n}'
end
```

In the above example, Selenium returns an "invalid URL" error message. De-bugging with Pry tells me that my 'url' object is not a single url, but rather still the entire array.

How can I set Selenium to visit each URL from the array one by one?

EDIT: ----------------
So, after extensive de-bugging with Pry, I found a couple issues. First being that my CSV was feeding a nested array to my loop which was causing the URL error. I had to flatten my array and un-nest it to get around that issue.

After that, I had to build a rescue into my loop so that my script didn't die when it encountered a page without the CSS element I was looking for.

Here's the finalized loop.

```
begin
        @urls1.each do |url|
          @driver.navigate.to(url)
          @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10

          name = @driver.find_element(:css, '.sites-embed- 
          footer>a').attribute('href')
          puts name
          kb_link = name
          kb_array.push(kb_link)
          puts 'done'

         rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
         puts 'no google doc'
         x = 'no google doc'
         kb_array.push(x)
         next
    end
```

Comment: `@driver.navigate.to #{url}` is an invalid ruby syntax.

Comment: How would I set a variable to tell Selenium to go to? I thought that by setting url as the variable for the loop I could interpolate the value as the destination for Selenium. Again, still new to Ruby so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `.each`?

Example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
array.each { |x| puts x }
```

In your code:

```
urls.each do |url|
    @driver.navigate.to #{url}
    name = @driver.find_element(:css, '.sites-embed-footer>a').attribute('href')
    puts name
    kb_link = name
    kb_array.push(kb_link)
    puts 'urls is #{n}'
end
```

Comment: With .each, I get a different error. 
  
    .rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver- 
    3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:31:in `to': wrong number of 
    arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

Comment: The problem is with the line `@driver.navigate.to`, can you use `@driver.navigate.to(url)`?

Comment: Script runs without errors now, but it doesn't seem to be actually running the loop. It runs pretty quickly and the CSV returns as empty.

Comment: When you are using Selenium, by default it will not wait until the rendering of the page Try this: `@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10` after the `@driver.navigate.to`

Comment: Each and map doesn't differ in the way you used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't make much sense to use `map` if you don't use the result of the block somewhere. `map`, applied to an Enumerable, returns a new Array, and you don't do anything with the returned array (which in your case would contain just the return values of `puts`, which is usually nil, so you would get back just an array of nils with the side effect that something is written to stdout.

If you are only interested in the side effects, `each` or `each_with_index`should be used to traverse an Enumerable. Given the problems you have with `map` **and** with `each`, I wonder what is the actual content of your object `urls`. Did you ever inspect it? You could do a

```
p urls
```

before entering the loop. With 3000 URLs, the output will be huge, but maybe you can run it on a simpler example with less URLs.

Comment: Doing this ended up solving my issue. My urls were all stored in a very nested array so each url was printing as [[[[url]]]]. Getting rid of the brackets made my Selenium driver.navigate.to work and I was able to traverse the array with .each (which I had originally wanted to do, but got somewhat frustrated around the time I posted this question). 

Problem solved, the script ran and I was finally able to get all the data I needed from the webpages. :)